# Difference between Component and Custom Element in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to understand the difference between the terms Component and Custom Element in the context of Aurelia.

From the docs, "components are composed of view and view-model pairs" (i.e. an HTML and a JS/TS file).  Is a "custom element" just the view (HTML file) half of that combination?  Or does a custom element also consist of a view and a view-model?

Answer (score 0):

Component is the model and view-model pair. It defines an Aurelia component. Quoting from their site: **Components are the basic building blocks of all Aurelia applications**. Custom element is the HTML custom element that can be included in the app's markup like `<my-element>`. It is defined in the component. Custom as opposed to the standard HTML elements such as `<div>`, `<p>` etc.

See

- http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/components/
- http://aurelia.io/docs/templating/custom-elements/

Comment: Even custom element can have a model and view-model, right? Both component and custom element is included as <my-element> or <my-component>. What exactly is the difference?

Comment: The aurelia-cli tools says otherwise: generate component... Creates a custom component class and template (**view model** and **view**), placing them in the project source folder (or optionally in sub folders).